# when I pip install, my packages are going in my macs local library

Tags: python, macos, pip

when I pip install a package it gets insalled on my macs library. I am using pycharm whih allows me to click on a package like a hyperlink. And instead of going to my site-packages in my virtualenv it's going to my macs library which is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gdata/youtube/
```

when it should be

```
  myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gdata/youtube/
```

why is that.

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should activate your virtual environment to install packages on that. In Pycharm you can do it like this:

Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Project` > `Project Interpreter`

Now you have to select the interpreter for this project. Browse or select the interpreter from drop-down if available. In your case this should be:

```
myproject/lib/python3.5
```

> I am using Pycharm community edition on Ubuntu. But the
>   process should be similar in Mac.

Comment: I think your answer fits but i only see the path to the wrong interpreter but if i click the add sign I see add local, add remote, add virtualenv. i dont think it's the last one since I already have a virtual env and remote is off site so I should choose add local?

Comment: it's still not working. I thoufght it was but it's not, Your solution that is. I deleted gdata from my macs library puth which turned gdata into a warning with red sqiggly under it. this just started happening out of no where.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a virtual environment for your project.

Install this tool virtualenv.

`$ pip install virtualenv`

Then create your project's folder

`$ cd my_project_folder`
`$ virtualenv venv`

This creates a copy of Python in whichever directory you ran the command in, placing it in a folder named venv.

Source

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv

For further knowledge read

https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 0):

You should install your virtual environment and then run pip within that environment. So, for example, I use Anaconda (which I thoroughly recommend if you are installing alot of scientific libraries).

To activate the environment "hle" I type in:

```
source /Users/admin/.conda/envs/hle/bin/activate hle
```

Once I've done this the pip command will reference the virtual environment location and not the standard mac location. So, when I install "mypackage" as follows:

```
pip install mypackage
```

It subsequently installs files in the virtual folder and not in the usual mac system folders.

You can find out about the Anaconda virtual environment (and download it) over here: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html but other virtual environments (like Virtualenv) work in the same way.